# data frames, input and output with files

Tags: r

I'm looking for a simple way to read/write a basic data frame:

```
symbMat <- matrix("AJY", "6A", "6J", 0, 0, ncol=5)
colnames(symbMat) <- c("Symb1","Symb2","Symb3","lastVstamp","completedRows")
testFrame<-List(symbMat,matrix(c("date1","date2")))
```

so testFrame now looks like

```
[[1]]
 Symb1 Symb2 Symb3 lastVstamp completedRows
[1,] "AJY" "6A"  "6J"  "0"        "0"          

[[2]]
     [,1]   
[1,] "date1"
[2,] "date2"
```

so the problem is that 
    read.table("MultiTable", header=TRUE)
gives me a file that treats it all as one 2x6 matrix (with a messed up name for the last column)

```
"Symb1" "Symb2" "Symb3" "lastVstamp" "completedRows" "structure.c..date1....date2.....Dim...c.2L..1L.."
"1" "AJY" "6A" "6J" "0" "0" "date1"
"2" "AJY" "6A" "6J" "0" "0" "date2"
```

while

```
 install.packages("MASS")
 library(MASS)
 write.matrix(testFrame,file="MultiTable")
```

just makes a file

AJY, 6A , 6J , 0  , 0
date1, date2

which is obviously quite a bit of information loss. Besides, there isn't a read.matrix() so I don't know what the point of that function is anyway

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `testFrame` is not a `data.frame`. A `data.frame` is a very specific object type in R. However, that does not impact being able to save and re-load data. There are two sets of functions for saving and loading data: `save()`/`load()` and `dump()`/`source()`. The first creates a binary format, the second a text format (though not structured the same as what is printed on screen).

Fixing the typos in your example:

```
symbMat <- matrix(c("AJY", "6A", "6J", 0, 0), ncol=5)
colnames(symbMat) <- c("Symb1","Symb2","Symb3","lastVstamp","completedRows")
testFrame<-list(symbMat,matrix(c("date1","date2")))
```

`testFrame` is

```
> testFrame
[[1]]
     Symb1 Symb2 Symb3 lastVstamp completedRows
[1,] "AJY" "6A"  "6J"  "0"        "0"          

[[2]]
     [,1]   
[1,] "date1"
[2,] "date2"
```

With `save()` and `load()`:

```
save(testFrame, file="temp.RData")
load(file="temp.RData")
```

With `dump()` and `source()`:

```
dump("testFrame", file="temp.R")
source(file="temp.R")
```

Note the first argument of `dump()` is quoted.  `temp.R` is then

```
testFrame <-
list(structure(c("AJY", "6A", "6J", "0", "0"), .Dim = c(1L, 5L
), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Symb1", "Symb2", "Symb3", "lastVstamp", 
"completedRows"))), structure(c("date1", "date2"), .Dim = c(2L, 
1L)))
```

which represents the object the same way as `dput()` does.